# jQuery file upload including variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

Is it possible to use a file upload using jQuery/javascript that would include usable variables? (user selects file)

For example. Could I upload a file (.txt, or .js etc) with the following contents and be able to use the variables?

`var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];`

`var name = "bob";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Please check below for more in depth.

**Add .txt or any files in formdata**

```
var formData = new FormData();

var txxtFile = $('#input_file').prop('files')[0];
formData.append('file',txxtFile);
```

**Append variables in formData**

```
var carsArray = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
formData.append(cars,  JSON.stringify(carsArray ));
```

Once you append all values to `formData` you have to pass `formData` in ajax request.

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: Are you able to provide a full HTML source that I can test? Im still getting use to this. Thanks.

Comment: The examples you have linked do not help me at all. The example linked seem far more complex than what I was asking and do not use a file (with variables) being uploaded and used.